# How can i make my .setFooter so if i dont specific footer text/img args its just null?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

How can i make my .setFooter the same as the rest of my embed?
To make it so if i dont specific footer text/img args its just null?

```
      .setTitle( args[1] ? args[1] : null)
      .setDescription( args[2] ? args[2] : null)
      .setFooter({ text: args[3], iconURL: args[4] })
      .setThumbnail( args[5] ? args[5] : null)
      .setImage( args[6] ? args[6] : null)
      .setColor( args[7] ? args[7] : null);
```

This is my current code, everything else works how i set it up however im not sure how to do that for .setFooter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need the ternary operator. Just use `args[1] || null`. This expression resolves to either `args[1]`, or, if that's a [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), `null`. For your `EmbedBuilder.setFooter()`, you would do this:

```js
EmbedBuilder
  // ...
  .setFooter({
    text: args[3] || null,
    iconURL: args[4] || null
  })
  // ...
```

Here's a more detailed explanation of this:
Take the expression `a || b`, given that `a` and `b` are of type `any`. If `a` is a [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), this returns `b`. Otherwise, it returns `a`.
This also works with functions, as shown in the following example:

```js
function a() { return 0; }
function b() { return -2048; }
function c() { return 4096 }
a || b  // Returns `-2048`
c || b  // Returns `4096`
```